# Get all items from adapter (recyclerview) in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, fragment, android-recyclerview

Hello I'm having an issue getting all of the items from my adapter in my fragment. To be more specific I am using a ScaleInAnimatorAdapter along with my Customer Adapter and when I attempt to get my checkbox items from the below posted code, within my Fragment, I only seem to get the visible items on screen.

```
private View.OnClickListener onAllClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        int count = listAdapter.getItemCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View mChild = listTopics.getChildAt(i);

            if( mChild != null ) {
                Log.d(TAG,"getItemCount(): " + i );

                CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox)mChild.findViewById(R.id.topic_chk);
                cBox.setChecked(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
                Log.d(TAG,"isChecked" + cBox.getTag());
                cBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                            checkboxAll.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Essentially I am attempting to create a check all feature from the fragment, so that when this is clicked all of the checkbox items from the adapter are checked. I got that to work with the code I presented however the main issue is that I only get the items visible on the screen, so when I scroll to my other items they are not checked. Thus I am wondering if there is a better way or another way for me to get all of the items

Answer (score 2):

Adapters are meant to bind underlying data stores to views; they generally shouldn't be used to store data themselves (except for having a copy of the data for view binding purposes) nor should they perform actions on data.

Instead, you should be modifying the underlying data, then updating the adapter through whatever mechanism you are already using. (Loaders, custom setters with notifyDataItemChanged, etc.).

Comment: Ok, I see now. I was misunderstanding that concept for some reason. So if I understood you correctly, instead I should for example in my Model, have a setChecked, isChecked and toggleChecked to update the data and in my adapter have some other methods which will update the view of the corresponding checkboxes based on that data.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you **can't**. It'll be **reusing** the UI views. 
You need to set a flag in all your data list objects, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `onBindViewHolder` check that flag and use it to check uncheck

```
if(listAdapter.getItem(position).getIsChecked())
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
else
   viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So I've initialized a flag in my view holder, which is set on the onBindViewHolder. So now in my Fragment I should check if the flag on each item, then update the flag, set the checkbox on teh view and call notifyDataSetChanged so that my recyclerview data is updated. Is that sort of what you are saying? Apologies if lack of code in this comment does not help

Comment: Yes. However i didn't understand this part "set the checkbox on the view" .. Rest seems to be ok.

Comment: So like visually set it, so set the checkbox on the view I just meant uncheck and check. Your viewholder object, are you initializing the view object and then initializing it with final TopicsListViewHolder holder = (TopicsListViewHolder) v.getTag(); or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Thank you all for those who have replied you helped me grasp something really basic and important that had alluded me.

I got it to work, so for anyone who might read this post, here is my solution:

- Create necessary methods and field to update your data in a model (ie, private is_checked, set_checked(), is_checked(), etc)
- In your adapter onBindViewHolder, you will set your holder checkbox to be associated to the data so something like:

  ```
  holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          obj.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
      }
  });
  holder.checkBox.setChecked(obj.isSelected());
  ```
- Then in your fragment or activity I just have a click listener on my main checkbox, and then when checked I loop through my data list, and using the model method I update my data and just simply use **listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrongly.
You should update the adapter instead of updating the check box view.

What you can do , you can create a field in adapter data holder .

And whenever you change the selection,just update the field or multiple field and finally refresh the view.